# How to determine the host Multi-Arch default folder

Tags: make, makefile, multiarch

I want to make a makefile that installs a library in the host default multi-arch folder, like `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` and `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf`.

But without using `dpkg-architecture` and `debhelper` as they are not always present on the host device.

Only using `gcc` and `make`.

I already found the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` folder. I could parse the *.conf files from there, but is this a correct approach? The multi-arch folder will always be there?

Another method I though is parsing the content of `ldconfig -v | grep /usr/lib/` and getting the first result (removing the collon).

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I will post the scripts for the methods I found. But if there is another default way, please post it.

Using the ldconfig:

```
ldconfig -v 2>>/dev/null | grep /usr/lib* | head --lines=1 | sed -e 's/://'
```

I guess that it can return another folder if someone config another search order, eg. adding another folder before the default host multiarch folder.

Using the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` folder:

```
lines=$(cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/* 2>>/dev/null)
for line in $lines ; do
    case "$line" in
    *Multiarch*)
        found_multiarch=1
        ;;
    /usr/lib/*)
        if [ "$found_multiarch" = 1 ] ; then
            folder=$line
            break
        fi
        ;;
    esac
done
echo $folder
```

It will return the first folder under `/usr/lib` that comes after the line with `*Multiarch*`.

Both scripts tested on armv7 and x86_64 (default installations, no foreign architectures) and returning the expected results.

Not tested in boxes with foreign architecture installed.

Comment: Yeah, it is reporting `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` on `x86_64` with foreign architecture installed. May be because of the order.

Comment: Thank you! I tested on another box. The ldconfig script does not work on these cases. But the second script worked like a charm!

Comment: My previous results was from the 2nd script. The 1st script also have an issue too, its result is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot` in the same system. I think you shouldn't relay on comments or order to extract the architecture folder path. When having 2 arch active, there will be a mixture of paths and we can't expect the order. May be it is more convenient to use `uname -i` to look for current running arch then check if arch specific folders exits in  `ldconfig` listing. Here the full raw output that may help you debug:  https://paste.ubuntu.com/23812802/

Comment: Thank you for your results! Unhappily they don't work. The question is: how ldconfig and gcc and dpkg-architecture know the default path? I will try to find the dpkg-architecture source code somewhere

Answer (score 1):

I followed `dpkg-architecture` which is just a Perl script:

```
$ which dpkg-architecture 
/usr/bin/dpkg-architecture

$ file /usr/bin/dpkg-architecture
/usr/bin/dpkg-architecture: a /usr/bin/perl script, UTF-8 Unicode text executable

$ more /usr/bin/dpkg-architecture
use Dpkg::Arch qw(get_raw_build_arch get_raw_host_arch get_host_gnu_type
                  debarch_to_cpuattrs
                  get_valid_arches debarch_eq debarch_is debarch_to_debtriplet
                  debarch_to_gnutriplet gnutriplet_to_debarch
                  debarch_to_multiarch);

$ man Dpkg::Arch

$ locate "Dpkg/Arch"
/usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Arch.pm

$ more /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Arch.pm

## this may fails if multi-arch is not supported
$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64

## it seems this what are you looking for
$ gcc -dumpmachine
x86_64-linux-gnu
```

One thing that could be a drawback, in `i386` installation `gcc -dumpmachine` reports `i686-linux-gnu`. It will work fine because `/usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu` is in `ldconfig` listing too same as `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`; However, the default created folder by Ubuntu is `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`.

Comment: `gcc -dumpmachine` worked! I guess it returns the triplet for the target platform instead of the host one, but it is fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: @BernardoRamos, I just tested a 32bit Ubuntu installation.  From `man gcc`,  yeah it show the target triplet. I just noticed one point about the i386 folder, see my update to the answer. You may want to force `i386-linux-gnu` in place of `i686-linux-gnu`

Comment: Oops! Then it will not work for my interests as I want to replace a pre-installed library, and it will be in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` in this case. Well, maybe the script can check for the file on both folders...

Comment: @BernardoRamos, you better avoid changing distribution libs that way, they will be overwritten on each update. Use  `/usr/local/lib/` which have priority over `/usr/lib`.